# Marvelous Hover - Deprecated Visual Composer plugin - Too few arguments to function error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, php-7, deprecated, visual-composer

I have a deprecated plugin (Marvelous Hover Effects | WPBakery Page Builder Add-on) on my WP site which stopped working.

The error message is like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: **Too few arguments to function VCEX_VC_Section_Config::custom_output(), 3 passed in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 303 and exactly 4 expected in /wp-content/themes/Total/inc/integration/wpbakery/classes/class-vcex-vc-section-config.php:307** 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 /wp-includes/**class-wp-hook.php(303)**: VCEX_VC_Section_Config::**custom_output**('<a\n href="/pro...', Object(Marvelous_Shortcode_Item), Array) 
> #1 /wp-includes/**plugin.php(189)**: WP_Hook->apply_filters('<a\n href="/pro...', Array) 
> #2 wp-content/plugins/vc-marvelous-hover/inc/shortcodes/**base.php(215)**: **apply_filters**('vc_shortcode_ou...', '<a\n href="/pro...', Object(Marvelous_Shortcode_Item), Array) 
> #3 /wp-content/plugins/vc-marvelous-hover/inc/shortcodes/**base.php(171)**: Marvelous_Shortcode_Base->output(Array, '') 
> #4 /home/julrgn/wwwroot/alu in /wp-content/themes/Total/inc/integration/wpbakery/classes/**class-vcex-vc-section-config.php on line 307**

The CMS and all the other modules are up-to-date (or almost), so I assume I have to do something with this one.

I checked all the functions mentioned but I couldn't figure out which one to modify and how:

class-wp-hook.php(303):
`$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );`

plugin.php(189):
`$filtered = $wp_filter[ $hook_name ]->apply_filters( $value, $args );`

**base.php(215):

`$output = apply_filters( 'vc_shortcode_output', $output, $this, $this->atts );`**

**base.php(170-171):

`public function render( $atts, $content = null, $tag = null ) {`

    `return $this->output( $atts, $content );}`**

class-vcex-vc-section-config.php(307):
`public static function custom_output( $output, $obj, $atts, $shortcode ) {`

According to the online sources I found, I modified the base.php but all my attempts was uneffective or produced new errors.

Maybe the problem is somewhere else?
I checked all the "add_action" calls but I couldn't figure out which one should I modify.

Could you help me sort this out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I modified this:

```
$output = apply_filters( 'vc_shortcode_output', $output, $this, $this->atts );
```

to this:

```
$output = apply_filters( 'vc_shortcode_output', $output, $this, $this->atts, null );
```

And now it works. :-)